# pickle.dump changes the object of array to binary. How to resolve that?

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to save an array of Objects to a file using `pickle.dump`. The resulting file gets converted to binary/encoded. Due to the requirements of the project I do not want that to happen and would like to save the array of objects as it is to a file.

My array looks like:

```
myArray = [
Rule(F1, HTTPS TCP, ['currentIP', 'ip'], ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443),
Rule(F4, HTTPS TCP, ['172.22.126.39', '172.23.94.9'], ['https://stackoverflow.com'], 443)
]
```

The resulting file looks like:

```
€•Ð      ]”(Œ__main__”ŒRule”“”)”}”(Œ
flowNumber”ŒF1”Œprotocol”Œ  HTTPS TCP”Œport”Œ443”ŒfromIP”]”(Œ
```

As seen some extra characters are added

```
class Rule:
    def __init__(self, flowNumber, protocol, port, fromIP=[], toIP=[]):
        self.flowNumber = flowNumber
        self.protocol = protocol
        self.port = port
        self.fromIP = fromIP
        self.toIP = toIP

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'\nRule({self.flowNumber}, {self.protocol}, {self.fromIP}, {self.toIP}, {self.port})'

rulesList = []
```

I tried the following to save into a file:

```
def saveResponseInFile(rulesList):
    with open("Rules.txt", "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(rulesList, file)
```

Is there a way to save the array as it is to a file?

**EDIT:**

I would like the saved file to look as:

```
Rule(F1, HTTPS TCP, ['currentIP', 'ip'], ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443),
Rule(F4, HTTPS TCP, ['172.22.126.39', '172.23.94.9'], ['https://stackoverflow.com'], 443)
```

OR

```
myArray = [
Rule(F1, HTTPS TCP, ['currentIP', 'ip'], ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443),
Rule(F4, HTTPS TCP, ['172.22.126.39', '172.23.94.9'], ['https://stackoverflow.com'], 443)
]
```

The reason being the resulting file would be sent to another script that expects the same as an input.

Comment: What do you mean by "as it is"?  The whole point of `pickle` is to write the data out in a format that can be read back in later, restoring the object to its exact original state.  To do that, it has to record the data types and the key names.  A Python object has no meaning outside of Python.  Why don't you tell us what you want to see in the file?  You can always do a custom serialization function, like JSON.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "as it is"? Do you want the output to look like the actual python code?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding I have updated my question

Comment: @TimRoberts I thought about using JSON but the other script expects the above as an input

Comment: Just modify your `__repr__` to produce the format you want and write it to a text file?

Comment: Kind of beside the point, but that's a list, not an array. Python's standard library does include arrays, but they're rarely used. Usually if Python code works with arrays, it's using the NumPy library.

Comment: @Timus I tried your approach just now that also results in addition of extra characters to the file

Comment: Who is going to load that back in?  Python can't read that format.

Comment: Does the other script process the file with `eval`?

Comment: @TimRoberts what could be the alternative solution to the problem

Comment: We have no idea what the problem IS.  You said you need a very precise format.  That must mean you have something that EXPECTS that format.  Right?  If this is just for saving something to be read later by Python, then the pickle is perfectly fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts the other server pull the file and tries to verify these firewall rules implemented using GitLab ci, if that helps . The way the other script works is it requires an array of Firewall Rules

Comment: @CrazyChucky I have not implemented that part yet, butu I can use ```eval``` if that works

Comment: `eval` is unsafe and not recommended. I was only asking because it seemed possible you already doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is almost right.  You just need to add the separating commas.

```
class Rule:
    def __init__(self, flowNumber, protocol, port, fromIP=[], toIP=[]):
        self.flowNumber = flowNumber
        self.protocol = protocol
        self.port = port
        self.fromIP = fromIP
        self.toIP = toIP

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Rule({self.flowNumber}, {self.protocol}, {self.fromIP}, {self.toIP}, {self.port})'

rulesList = [
Rule('F1', 'HTTPS TCP', ['currentIP', 'ip'], ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443),
Rule('F4', 'HTTPS TCP', ['172.22.126.39', '172.23.94.9'], ['https://stackoverflow.com'], 443)
]

for rule in rulesList:
    print(f"{rule},")
```

Output:

```
Rule(F1, HTTPS TCP, ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443, ['currentIP', 'ip']),
Rule(F4, HTTPS TCP, ['https://stackoverflow.com'], 443, ['172.22.126.39', '172.23.94.9']),
```

Again, however, Python can't read that in, in part because the strings are not quoted.

Comment: Thank you for your ans and discussing the solution, I converted the array to str, the file looks better with only a few extra characterstics. I might try to clean the input before using it.

Comment: @ritvikseth What extra characters are you getting?

Comment: @CrazyChucky the resulting file looks like ` €•ê      ]”(ŒY
Rule(F1, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443)”ŒL
Rule(F2, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['75.2.18.233'], 443)”ŒM
Rule(F3, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['ip7'], 443)”ŒZ`

Comment: So anything not in a Rule are extra, such as  €•ê ]”(ŒY, ŒL

Comment: You are certainly not getting any of those characters with the code I'm showing.  What you're showing is the result from `pickle`, which you need to throw out.  I even showed you the output my script produced.  I always run the code in my answers.

Comment: Yes I know that the extra characteristics are produced from '''pickle'''

Comment: Then don't use pickle. It's not intended for what you're trying to do with it.